# How to use v-for in Vue with two mysql table to get wanted data?

Tags: sequelize.js, vue-directives

I have two tables buyer and seller in phpMyAdmin. I want to get data from these two tables in Vue.
I have used sequelize ORM. Problem is that it gives more data than wanted. How can I solve this ?
I have also tried association but it is not working. It gives both table data at once not only
the buyer question or seller answer. I want to show buyer question first and then seller answer.
Please help me. Thanks in Advance!

```
   <div id="app">
<div v-for="i in seller" :key="i.id">
    <div v-for="p in buyer" :key="p.id">
         <p>{{i.seller_name}}</p>
         <p>{{p.buyer_name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting the two `v-for` (the buyer v-for is *inside* the seller v-for). So for every seller you are printing every buyer.

I would add a computed property that associate each seller with its buyer:

```
computed: {
   purchases () {
      const buyers = this.buyer
      return this.seller.map((seller, index) => {
          return {
             seller: seller.seller_name,
             buyer: buyers[index].buyer_name,
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Note: this code assumes seller and buyer are arrays with the same length. If this is not the case, you may need some additional checks.

Then in your template:

```
<div v-for="purchase in purchases" :key="purchase.seller + purchase.buyer">
    <p>{{ purchase.seller }}</p>
    <p>{{ purchase.buyer }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but this is not exactly I want. Seller and buyer are not the same length of arrays. This is the problem.
How can I get buyer data first(Buyer question) then after get seller answer data.
Buyer post his/her question to ask how much of it?(things) And after that seller reply answer to them.
I have worked on your code but it didn't meet my answer.Thanks.

Comment: buyer and seller are arrays or a single object? I assumed they were arrays because you were looping over them